# Iron Router inside package: cannot find template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using Iron Router inside a package, and it complains that it cannot find a template, even though I have defined it.

I have defined a template called `layout` inside my package: `client/templates/shared/layout.html`

And I have required that file in `package.js` like this:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');

  api.use('iron:router@1.0.9');

  api.addFiles([
    'both/routes.js'
  ], ['client', 'server']);

  api.addFiles([
    'client/templates/shared/layout.html',
    'client/templates/home.html'
  ], 'client');
});
```

And I am using `layout` template in my route definition file, `both/routes.js`

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  template: 'home'
});
```

And in my main app, I am using this package. It can be found at `.meteor/packages`.

But when I navigate to `/`, I get

```
Couldn't find a template named "layout" or "layout". Are you sure you defined it?
```

I tried to restart the server without success. What am I missing?

Comment: wild guess, try adding html files first and then router file inside package file using `api.addFiles` ???

Comment: @Sasikanth I tried all combinations with `api.use` and two `api.addFiles` but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also need the following two:

`api.use(['templating'], 'client'); // The templating package`

`api.export('layout'  ['client', 'server']); // Export your template.`

Comment: Adding `api.use('templating', 'client');` did the trick. For anyone having the similar issue, see [templating](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/templating#templating)